# React Native app getting stuck on white screen

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a react native app that's running on React Native 0.51.0, Xcode 9.2, exclusively on iOS 11.X (mostly 11.2.5/6) iPad Pros.

After upgrading from 0.38.X to 0.49.X, I started noticing a white screen on loading, like the app wasn't starting to load the React Native bundle.  I have since upgraded React Native to 0.51.0, but the problem persists.

To add a bit of color to this issue, one thing I noticed was after successfully seeing the app load to the home screen, there was one particular transition that would immediately lead to a stuck white screen again.  The logs for that issue showed an issue with one of the React Native `<Animated.View>` objects.  I noticed that I had added the `RCTAnimation.xcodeproj` to the parent project, but the `libRCTAnimation.a` was no longer linked in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section.  After adding the lib back to being linked, that particular white screen went away, and `<Animated.View>` worked properly.

At this point, I've triple checked that all of my included React Native projects are linked properly.  At this point, I'm not quite sure which ones are still 100% required, but the list is as follows (xcodeproj and verified linked lib):

- React.xcodeproj > libReact.a
- RCTAnimation.xcodeproj > libRCTAnimation.a
- RCTActionSheet.xcodeproj > libRCTActionSheet.a
- RCTGeolocation.xcodeproj > libRCTGeolocation.a
- RCTImage.xcodeproj > libRCTImage.a
- RCTLinking.xcodeproj > libRCTLinking.a
- RCTNetwork.xcodeproj > libRCTNetwork.a
- RCTSettings.xcodeproj > libRCTSettings.a
- RCTText.xcodeproj > libRCTText.a
- RCTVibration.xcodeproj > lib RCTVibration.a
- RCTWebSocket.xcodeproj > libRCTWebSocket.a
- RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj > libRCTCameraRoll.a
- RNBlur.xcodeproj > libRNBlur.a
- BVLinearGradient.xcodeproj > libBVLinearGradient.a
- RNVectorIcons.xcodeproj > libRNVectorIcons.a
- BugsnagReactNative.xcodeproj > libBugsnagReactNative.a
- ART.xcodeproj > libART.a

Here is my AppDelegate start up code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  CrashReporter.configureCrashReporting()

  // Initialize various objects and connections
  self.configureApplication()

  window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  self.window?.rootViewController = self.createRootViewController(launchOptions: launchOptions)
  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

  return true
}

func createRootViewController(launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> UIViewController {
  let rootViewController = UIViewController()
  rootViewController.view = self.createReactRootView(launchOptions: launchOptions)

  return rootViewController
}

func createReactRootView(launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> UIView? {
  let jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index.ios", fallbackResource: nil)
  let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "app", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions: launchOptions)
  rootView?.backgroundColor = .white
  return rootView
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two examples of white screens (this was a long solution...)

White Screen #1:

At some point, React Native no longer allows the `<Image>` View to have children.  When the app hit the state where we add a child to one of our `<Image>` views, the screen would go white.  This was at least followed up with a print statement to the log indicating the problem.

White Screen #2 (The main one):

As of iOS 11, we've noticed a different behavior when calling `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` *from the main thread*.  It seems like this is ripe for creating deadlock situations (we've literally left the thing running for hours with no progress); maybe this is a bug in Apple's Dispatch Queueing system?

One of our React Native bridge objects was calling `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` inside of its constructor.  This was never completing, blocking the main thread, and so the rest of React Native would not proceed to load (it wouldn't even get to loading the bundle).  Nothing would print, and pausing the debugger at this point never produce usable state.

We simply removed the wrapping `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` and are calling these statements in-line, as it's already on the main thread.